# On `go build` creating cgo headerfile

Tags: go, cgo

Short of it is in the title... I'm trying to have the headerfile that cgo already creates `cgo_export.h`  - but sticks in the working directory - created in a static location that I can reliably access (as working directories can and should change). Directly using `cgo` provides for a `-headerfile` option, but I see no such option within the build options of `go build`, nor a way of passing options to `cgo` from `go build`.

Besides using a second run of `cgo`(or some script to grab the header each time from the working directory) is there any way to produce the header file with `go build`

Comment: A build doesn't happen in the current directory. Would the `-work` flag suffice, which leaves the temp working directory?

Comment: @JimB - I am using that flag - that is essentially what I was referring to with 'some script to grab the header each time from the working directory' - Do you suppose that is my only option, write a post-compilation script that grabs the header from the work directory after compilation?

Comment: Yes, you would need to copy it from the temp dir, or generate it with the cgo tool. If you're not building a C shared library, why do you need the header?

Comment: Just for ease of use. In-editor autocomplete. The niceties is all, no functional NEED, just a developer's *want*.